# Let $a$ be the largest integer strictly smaller than $\frac {7b}8$ where $b$ is also an integer. Check the validity of the two inequalties.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

Let $a$ be the largest integer strictly smaller than $\frac {7b}8$ where $b$ is also an integer. Comment on  the validity of the inequalities $\frac{7b}8 -a\leq 1$ and $\frac{7}{8}b-a\geq \frac 18$ with respect to these context.

I tried a few examples and intuitively, I could figure it out that $\frac{7b}8 -a\leq 1$ is valid in all sense. But the inequality $\frac{7b}8 -a\geq \frac 18$ is confusing me. I feel that this inequality is also valid and a true one, just by looking at some trivial examples, but can't convince myself intuitively. Any clarification regarding this is anticipated.

Comment: Fix the inequalities in your solution, they are incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first inequality :

Suppose that $\frac{7b}8 -a\gt 1$. Then, we have $\frac{7b}{8}\gt a+1>a$. This contradicts that $a$ is the largest integer strictly smaller than $\frac{7b}{8}$. Therefore, we have $\frac{7b}8 -a\leq 1$.

For the second inequality :

We have $\frac{7b}{8}-a\gt 0$, i.e. $7b-8a\gt 0$. Since $7b$ and $8a$ are integers, we have $7b-8a\ge 1$. Dividing the both sides by $8$, we get $\frac{7b}{8}-a\ge\frac 18$.